# Getting Python script tool to take list of variables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool

I am looking at making a Python script tool that requires the user to input a series of attributes into a list, which is then used to build a query, to select multiple polygons (i.e. "abc, 123"; "def, 456").

I understand how to script this, but how do I get the script tool to take the arguments?

Comment: Are you creating a python toolbox script (.pyt) or a script tool in a regular toolbox (.tbx)?

Comment: I am creating a script tool in a toolbox.

Comment: If neither of the Answers offered so far are Accept-able then I think we need more details, like a working code snippet with hard coded examples of the variable values you are hoping to pass in as parameters, edited into your Question.

Answer (score 6):

If you are creating a script tool in a regular toolbox, when defining the tools parameters, for the parameter you want to pass as a list, set the "MultiValue" property to Yes. The multiple values will get passed to your script as a semi-colon separated string. To use as a list in your python script, split the string on the semi-colon, i.e:

```
lst_arg=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(n).split(';')
```

See this [help topic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000000n000000) for more information on script tool parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't actually let me type anything into the MultiValue property, any thoughts on that?

Comment: @user25074 - You don't type "Yes", it's a dropdown/pick list. Click on "No" and select "Yes" instead.

Comment: @user25074 - If you mean you can't type anything when trying to run the tool (as opposed to setting the parameter properties). If you have set your parameter type to "String", change it to "Any Value".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sys module or arcpy module to input these arguments:
i.e.

```
import sys,arcpy
# Version 1 - this will give you a python list of the arguments you enter
input_arguments = sys.argv
# i.e. input_arguments will = ['abc,123','def,456']

# Version 2

first_argument = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
second_argument = arcpy.GetParameter(1)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to write script
The one who specifies inserting a list from Attribute into the Toolbox is the Validation script
Below you will find the code that displays the contents of five fields from the table and choose them hierarchically, or you can choose from each field independently if you modify the tool code:

```
'''
import arcpy
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
fc="C:/LUCS/System_shapes/new.shp"
col1=  ("Field1_NAME")
col2=  ("Field2_NAME")
col3=  ("Field3_NAME") 
col4=  ("Field4_NAME")
col5=  ("Field5_NAME") 
Level1list=[]
Level1list_uniq=[]
Level2list=[]
Level2list_uniq=[]
Level3list=[]
Level3list_uniq=[]
Level4list=[]
Level4list_uniq=[]
Level5list=[]
Level5list_uniq=[]

class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""
  def __init__(self):  
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""  
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()  
  
  def initializeParameters(self):  
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is  
    called when the tool is opened."""  
    return  
  def updateParameters(self):
##___________level1________________________
    self.params[0].filter.list = [str(val) for val in  
                                    sorted(  
                                      set(  
                                        row.getValue(col1)  
                                        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, None, None,col1)))]  
    if self.params[0].value not in self.params[0].filter.list:  
      self.params[0].value = self.params[0].filter.list[0]
##___________level2____________________________
    if self.params[0].value:
        if self.params[1].value not in self.params[1].filter.list:  
              self.params[1].filter.list =Level1list_uniq
        cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
        for row in cursor:
                        if (row.getValue(col1)) ==(str(self.params[0].value)):
                                Level1list.append (row.getValue(col2))
        for elem in Level1list:
                        if elem not in Level1list_uniq:
                            Level1list_uniq.append(elem)
        if self.params[1].value not in self.params[1].filter.list:  
              self.params[1].filter.list =Level1list_uniq
      ##________________level3_________________        
        cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
        for row in cursor:
                  if (row.getValue(col1)) ==(str(self.params[0].value)):
                    if (row.getValue(col2)) ==(str(self.params[1].value)):
                            Level2list.append (row.getValue(col3))
        for elem in Level2list:
                    if elem not in Level2list_uniq:
                        Level2list_uniq.append(elem)
        if self.params[2].value not in self.params[2].filter.list:  
              self.params[2].filter.list =Level2list_uniq
      ##________________level4_______________       
        cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
        for row in cursor:
              if (row.getValue(col1)) ==(str(self.params[0].value)):
                if (row.getValue(col2)) ==(str(self.params[1].value)):
                    if (row.getValue(col3)) ==(str(self.params[2].value)):
                         Level3list.append (row.getValue(col4))
        for elem in Level3list:
                    if elem not in Level3list_uniq:
                        Level3list_uniq.append(elem)
        if self.params[3].value not in self.params[3].filter.list:  
              self.params[3].filter.list =Level3list_uniq
      ##________________level5_______________      
        cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
        for row in cursor:
              if (row.getValue(col1)) ==(str(self.params[0].value)):
                if (row.getValue(col2)) ==(str(self.params[1].value)):
                    if (row.getValue(col3)) ==(str(self.params[2].value)):
                      if (row.getValue(col4)) ==(str(self.params[3].value)):
                            Level4list.append (row.getValue(col5))
        for elem in Level4list:
                    if elem not in Level4list_uniq:
                        Level4list_uniq.append(elem)
        if self.params[4].value not in self.params[4].filter.list:  
              self.params[4].filter.list =Level4list_uniq
    return
  def updateMessages(self):  
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool  
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""  


  

'''
```